# Ajax Contact Us Form Validation - Cakephp 2.0

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-ajaxhelper

I'm having a website http://1008designs.in/ There in the home page I have built a Enquiry Form, The form usual validation works fine, but I need Jquery & Ajax validation, the form submits to 'enquiry/add', Pls help me on how to use Jquery Ajax in cakephp 2.0, I gone through a video of Andrew Perkins, but It didn't work for me. If I submit the form, then the whole home page is displayed on that Enquiry Div. I'm trying it from a week, but not working, pls help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit form with ajax to controller `enquiry/add` the html returend by ajax request is a view associated with this `enquiry/add`. If you want to customize this html you have to modify `add` action in controller:

At the end of the action try this:

```
if($this->request->is('ajax'))
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->render('/elements/enquiry_success');
}
```

And in app/view/elements/ add enquiry_success.ctp containing some html/php code which will be returned to #succces div (for example `<p>Enquiry added!!!</p>`).

This code detects if request is ajax and id it is it doesnt render default view for action but some element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed it, I used some other way, I used like [$this->render('success','ajax');]
What this does is it calls the success.ctp from the same folder & uses the ajax.ctp in layouts.